# iphone like annotation on android map

Tags: android, dictionary, overlay

Inside my android map I have three overlays looking like this:
[image: enter image description]

what I want is when I tap on each overlay to obtain something like an iphone callout. Something similar with what you see on the second picture, on the top of the overlay.

So: When I tap an overlay on the top of it I want to get something like in second picture...and when I click that callout I want to get to a new activity.Any idea how?????
Thank you!

[image: enter image description]

EDIT:

When the user taps  my overlys I've done this, the problem is that the dialog box appears on the middle of the screnn not on the top of the overlay tapped.How do I get that?

```
    @Override
        protected boolean onTap(int i) {

          AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(NotificationsActivity.this);
          //dialog.setTitle(items.getTitle());
          dialog.setMessage(items.get(i).getSnippet());
          dialog.show();
          return true; 
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a project [MapViewBallons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons#readme)

download that project..
open it in Eclipse

Goto Properties and the Android section and make sure
is Library check box is checked.

now Open your project properties got android section from left

and add MapViewBallonsProject as a library project.

Comment: There are two projects there: android-mapviewballons and android-mapviewballons-example....which should I open?

Answer (score 0):

Look up CustomViews and Opacity and How maps uses point on a map. ItemizedOverlay would be a good start.

**An example**

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Comment: try googling yourself. There are tons of examples.