# Set Name and Title on google map position in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-markers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iphone like annotation on android map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126811/iphone-like-annotation-on-android-map)

I am implementing an application that uses google maps.To the moment I was successfully able to mark locations on google map. But what I exactly need is to set a title on top of the google map position. Just like image below.

Can anybody help me out?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are you developing for iOS or Android?

Comment: ` MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Latitude, longitude));
        markerOptions.title(mapMarkerTitle);
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        /* To always show map marker title */
        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        marker.showInfoWindow(); `

Answer (score 2):

Its basically called Mapview Ballons. Here is the sample project developed on github for your reference. It will help me a lot in my project.

[Mapview Ballons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks Scorpion. I'l give a shot :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alertbox/Dialog box in ItemizedOverlay by using onTap method..

*You can mark as many places you like and you can set a title on top of of the google map position.*

***For Example***

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle b)
    {
        super.onCreate(b);
        try{  

            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            System.out.println(""+lati+place+longi+position.get(0)+position.size());
            mapView=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.map_view);
            mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 

            mc = mapView.getController();
            mc.setZoom(12);

            drae=this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            test tt=new test(drae,this);        
            tt.addit(latitude,longitude, place_name);
            tt.addit(latitude1,longitude1, place_name1);
            mapView.getOverlays().add(tt);
            System.out.println(ii);

            break;
        }


        default:
            System.out.println(position.size());
        }
    }
}

        }catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    class test extends ItemizedOverlay
    {
        List<OverlayItem>overLayItem=new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        Context con;
        public test(Drawable drae,Context con) {

            super(boundCenterBottom(drae));
            testt(con);
        }

        void testt(Context con)
        {
            this.con=con;
        }
        @Override
        protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
            return overLayItem.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return overLayItem.size();
        }

        protected boolean onTap(int index) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            OverlayItem ir=overLayItem.get(index);
            AlertDialog.Builder dia=new AlertDialog.Builder(con);
            dia.setTitle(ir.getTitle());
            dia.setMessage(ir.getSnippet());
            dia.setPositiveButton("close",new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dia.show();
            return true;
        }


        public void additem(OverlayItem item)
        {
            overLayItem.add(item);
            populate();
        }
        public void addit(int l,int g,String s)
        {
            GeoPoint po=new GeoPoint(l, g);
            OverlayItem it=new OverlayItem(po,s,null);
            additem(it);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the new [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) that was just released.  It makes adding markers with info windows (with title and snippet) much easier - see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker) for an example.